# iOS: Programmatically calling Container View

Tags: ios, subviews, uicontainerview

Before the `Main` View Controller is called, through a delegate I'll notify `Main` View Controller whether to call `TVC1` or `TVC2` in `Container View`.

Question: How can I programmatically tell the `Container View` in `Main View Controller` to call `TVC1`  or `TVC2`?

```
TVC1 *tvc1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TVC1"]; 
TVC2 *tvc2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TVC2"];
```

Where and how do I tell the `Container View` to `load` one of these controllers upon loading `Main` View Controller?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

through delegate u can know which view will be added so u can manage it by using any bool value n in `viewDidLoad` you can load that view by putting one condition

in mainController:

```
bool isFirstView;

-(void)delegate:(bool)isFirst
{
  isFirstView = isFirst;
}

// in viewDidLoad 
)
(void)viewDidLoad
{
  if(isFirstView)
  {
    TVC1 *tvc1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TVC1"]; 
  }
  else
  {
    TVC2 *tvc2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TVC2"];
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm struggling with the code.  How do I tell the Container View what controller it should load?  TVC1 *tvc1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TVC1"];
    TVC2 *tvc2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tvc2"];
Now where and how do I load these controllers?

Comment: it depends on u if u want to create it using storyboard then u have to maake a instance on nav controller by that u can call this tvc1 n tvc2 in view didload method by getting which view u want to load using any bool value by true or false

Comment: How does that view automatically gets called in Container View?

Comment: you can perform the segue by using the reference of this view controller

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using custom Container View Controller which will manage child view controllers.

[image]

There is a good tutorial for that:

http://sandmoose.com/post/35714028270/storyboards-with-custom-container-view-controllers